# Matching parent's width on iOS works but doesn't work on Mac OS (SwiftUI)

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm trying to stretch a view inside a HStack. The problem is the same code that works on iOS does not work on Mac OS and I can't find any logical reason. Am I missing something?

```
 HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Button("A") {

        }
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text("HELLO")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.red)
        }
        Button("B") {

        }
}.padding()
```

**Mac os output not stretching the button**

[image: mac os output]

**The same code working on iOS**

[image: iOS output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` and `fixedSize()`(optioanl fixedSize())

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("HELLO")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding()
        .background(Color.red)
        .fixedSize()
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

Comment: It works! but only without the fixedSize(). The `PlainButtonStyle` is enough

Comment: Yes. It's optional