# SwiftUI Button Size/Shape/Color Not Changing

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to make custom buttons for a MacOS app using SwiftUI, however, I seem to be unable to resize the button area and the button's color doesn't seem to be changeable. All the examples I find online say to either use .frame or .padding to set width and height but that doesn't change the shape of the button. Has anyone else experienced this while developing a MacOS app? [Image of button here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXd9M.png)

```
struct customButton: View {
    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            print("Delete button tapped!")
        }) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "trash")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .imageScale(.large)
                Text("Delete")
            }
            .padding()
            .background(
                Capsule().strokeBorder(Color.white, lineWidth: 1.25)
            )
        }
        .accentColor(Color.white)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matching parent's width on iOS works but doesn't work on Mac OS (SwiftUI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65881970/matching-parents-width-on-ios-works-but-doesnt-work-on-mac-os-swiftui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` to get rid of the default button UI.

```
Button(action: {
    print("Delete button tapped!")
}) {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "trash")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .imageScale(.large)
        Text("Delete")
    }
    .padding()
    .background(
        Capsule().strokeBorder(Color.white, lineWidth: 1.25)
    )
}
.accentColor(Color.white)
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling at finding my way around the documentation. This problem has plagued me for weeks now